# Keep date in loc search

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pivot table date and item as the index and price and quantity as values.
I can of course loop each date's transaction and do something with them using:

df

```
                           price  quantities
date           product                    
2016-01-01     apple        10.0    60.0
               orange       10.0     0.0
2017-01-01     apple        10.0    60.0
               orange       10.0     0.0

dates = df.index.levels[0]

for date in dates:
  productlists.append(df.loc[date])
```

result:

```
         price  quantities
product                    
apple     10.0    60.0
orange    10.0     0.0

         price  quantities
product                   
apple     10.0    60.0
orange    10.0     0.0
```

expected:

```
                           price  quantities
date           product                    
2016-01-01     apple        10.0    60.0
               orange       10.0     0.0
                            price  quantities
date           product 
2017-01-01     apple        10.0    60.0
               orange       10.0     0.0
```

The problem is now I lost the date index in the productlists. What should I do?

EDITED: provided with my expectation of result.

Comment: can you provide a minimal example of what's in `df`?

Answer (score 0):

`df.groupby(...)` returns an iterator which yields group-keys and each group as a sub-DataFrame. Therefore, you could use

```
productlists = [grp for key, grp in df.groupby(level=0)]
```

---

For example,

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'date': ['2016-01-01', '2016-01-01', '2017-01-01', '2017-01-01'],
 'price': [10.0, 10.0, 10.0, 10.0],
 'product': ['apple', 'orange', 'apple', 'orange'],
 'quantities': [60.0, 0.0, 60.0, 0.0]})
df = df.set_index(['date', 'product'])
productlists = [grp for key, grp in df.groupby(level=0)]
for grp in productlists:
    print(grp)
```

prints

```
                    price  quantities
date       product                   
2016-01-01 apple     10.0        60.0
           orange    10.0         0.0
                    price  quantities
date       product                   
2017-01-01 apple     10.0        60.0
           orange    10.0         0.0
```